# Calling a js function from select option

Tags: javascript, html

In html page

```
<form>
            <select id="selectWork" onchange='getWorkLocation(this.value);' class="span6">
                <option value="All">Hepsi</option>
                <option value="C">Ç</option>
                <option value="E">E</option>
                <option value="H">H</option>
                <option value="K">K</option>
                <option value="K">K</option>
                <option value="M">M</option>
                <option value="T">T</option>
            </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    require(["webRequest"], function (webRequest) {
function getWorkLocation(a) {
            if (a == "Hepsi") {
                getWorks();
            }
            else {
                webRequest.get("api/Work/GetWorkByType", { "type": a },
                    self.getWorkLocationSucceeded);
            }
        }
```

I am trying to call `getWorkLocation` function, but I got this error: `getWorkLocation is undefined.` What's wrong?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: hayır kardeşim kullanmıyorum :)

Answer (score 0):

As you're using [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) already (`$(function () { ... })` is jQuery syntax), you can remove the `onchange` attribute completely and instead use:

```
$('form').on('change', '#selectWork', function() {
    var text = $(this).text(); // "Hepsi" if A is selected

    if (text === "Hepsi")
        ...
});
```

Check out http://try.jquery.com and http://learn.jquery.com if you're unfamiliar with the library.

Answer (score 0):

Move the definition of getWorkLocation to the global scope.

```
require(["webRequest"], function (webRequest) {
    function getWorkLocation(a) {
        if (a == "Hepsi") {
            getWorks();
        }
        else {
            webRequest.get("api/Work/GetWorkByType", { "type": a },
                self.getWorkLocationSucceeded);
        }
    }

    // make getWorkLocation publically available
    window.getWorkLocation = getWorkLocation;
});
```

Since it looks like you are using require.js, there is no need to define the function inside a jQuery domready event handler.

Still, you have a race condition here. It is possible for the `onchange` event to fire on the select box before require.js has a chance to download the script and execute your callback.

To borrow from James Donnelly's answer, remove the inline `onchange` attribute from the select tag and use jQuery:

```
require(["webRequest"], function (webRequest) {
    ...
});

$(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#selectWork', function() {
        getWorkLocation(this.value);
    });
});
```